# Where can I get a visual example of the entire bitcoin network starting from physical network to the overlay network

Tags: transactions, mining-pools, nodes

***Note I am not a technical person so excuse any misunderstandings on my part here.**

I am looking to get a sense of how the entire system looks like as a whole starting from the physical hardware (such as miners and full nodes) to overlaying networks (node transaction relays maybe?) to mobile clients omitting and receiving transaction data.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, I believe there is a diagram like that in the O'Reily book *Mastering Bitcoin* by Andreas Antonopoulos.  It shows the different types of nodes and how they interact on the network.

Comment: That is true. I do recall getting a visual representation of various types of nodes and SPV wallets but  I was more reffering to something more similar to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlay_network#/media/File:Network_Overlay.svg